# Find value in background workbook

Tags: vba, excel, find

I am struggling to create a code to search for a value within a workbook that I am accessing without bringing it to the foreground.  I am using the following code to access the file as "xl0":

```
'DATABASE ACCESS
Dim xl0 As New Excel.Application
Dim xlw As New Excel.Workbook
Dim db_directory As String
db_directory = "R:\New Quality Management System\xls\Supplier Non-Conformance\Supplier Non-Conformance Database.xlsm"
Set xlw = xl0.Workbooks.Open(db_directory)
```

I have successfully had this working to add records to the xl0 spreadsheet however I also need to create a modify record macro to "find" an index value and extract the row number.  I tried several variations (2 examples below) with no success, can anyone advise?

Eg 1.

```
Windows("Supplier Non-Conformance Database.xlsm").Activate
Cells.Find(What:="2015-16-46", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
```

Eg 2.

```
xl0.Worksheets("SNCR Log").Range("B:B").Find(What:="2015-16-46",
After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
```

Thanks in advance,

Dan

Comment: What is your main problem? To do this in background, identify a row to copy or extract the row number?

Comment: I need to identify the row to use in later functions.  I've had no problem doing this within the same document it is purely doing so from another "non visible" workbook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a start :
(btw, the activation is really greedy in resources, so try to avoid it as much as possible!)

```
Application.ScreenUpdating=False

'DATABASE ACCESS
Dim xl0 As New Excel.Application
Dim xlw As New Excel.Workbook
Dim db_directory As String

xl0.Visible=False

db_directory = "R:\New Quality Management System\xls\Supplier Non-Conformance\Supplier Non-Conformance Database.xlsm"
Set xlw = xl0.Workbooks.Open(db_directory)

MsgBox xlw.Sheets(1).Cells.Find(What:="2015-16-46", LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Row


Application.ScreenUpdating=True
```

Comment: Thanks for this but it's not working for me.  It's prompting the compile error for the ".Cells" component.

Comment: Added some modifications : put an index for sheets (works for me) and as `After` is not mandatory, I delete it.

Comment: Spot on now.  Added the sheet name in as a fail safe and used as a variable.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: I'm having a similar issue with a CountIf statement now if you could help at all without starting a new post?  When I try it with a range in the same document but I have tried the following 2 methods for the external document with a MsgBox to output the variable:

"Test = xlw.Sheets(1).Application.CountIf(Range("B:B"), Report_ID)" and 
"Test = Application.CountIf(xlw.Sheets(1).Range("B:B"), Report_ID)"

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/office/hh211481%28v=office.14%29.aspx    to use a worksheet function it's like this `WorksheetFunction.CountIf(..)` and you first proposal is deeeply wrong, check by pressing F2 and look for "Sheets" if you "Application" inside, it definitely won't!