# VBA CountIf external document

Tags: excel, vba, countif

Following from my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29488845/find-value-in-background-workbook/29489018?noredirect=1#comment47141420_29489018), I am now struggling to create a working Application.CountIf function.  I am using the following code to access the file as "xl0":

```
'DATABASE ACCESS
Dim xl0 As New Excel.Application
Dim xlw As New Excel.Workbook
Dim db_directory As String
db_directory = "R:\New Quality Management System\xls\Supplier\Non-Conformance\Supplier Non-Conformance Database.xlsm"
Set xlw = xl0.Workbooks.Open(db_directory)
```

I can create a function to search the same open document no problem...

```
Test = Application.CountIf(Range("B:B"), Report_ID)
MsgBox (Test)
```

...but neither of the methods I've tried for searching in the document open in the background have worked...

```
Test = Application.CountIf(xlw.Sheets("SNCR Log").Range("B:B"), Report_ID)
```

...and...

```
Test = xlw.Sheets("SNCR Log").Application.CountIf(Range("B:B"), Report_ID)
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a guess, did not test it, but as Application refers to your current open application and you want to search within the xl0 application try

```
xl0.CountIf(...)
```

and see if that helps.

Comment: I have tried both the application and the workbook with no success.  I have tried with a WorksheetFunction and without, with the worksheet defined and without, all with no success.

Comment: So I think I got the solution. The following should work for you, just tested it with a test script: 
   
`Test = xl0.CountIf(xl0.Range("B:B"), Report_ID)`

Comment: Sorted!  Head in hands moment.  Not sure How I've not got this working before now!  Thanks for the help.